# Visual Studio Cordova iOS Remote Build Release Mode Error Code 70

Tags: ios, cordova, build, cocoapods

I'm trying to build my cordova app and get iOS .ipa file for publishing on app store.

I'm using **phonegap-plugin-push** plugin which requires **cocoapods**. All plugins and pods are installed successfully. 
**Debug** build is also successful and I'm able to run my app on Simulators.

[image]

When I'm trying to build a release mode for getting .ipa file, I always receive an error:

***Build failed with error code 70 ...***

I think the problem is that remote builder is trying to build by **.xcodeproj** file. 
When I've opened my project in **XCode** with **.xcodeproj** file and tried to build it, I've got the same error and problem was missing cocoapod plugin.
But when I opened my app with **.xcodeworkspace** file in **XCode** and built it, build was successful (cause all cocoapod plugins were included).

Any ideas how to fix release mode remote build in visual studio when using cocoapods?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any fix for this?

Comment: I gave up and completely removed cocoapods